# SSRS Graded colour scale

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

Can SSRS make a graded colour scale (like Excel). I am attatching an image to explain what I mean.

[image]

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not very easy. You can use an expression to dynamically set the `fill color` of a cell. The colors can be specified with their hex representation like `"#AC9494"`. You will have to come up with a formula to define which colors the scale goes through.

Red is "#FF0000" and green is "#00FF00". So your formula would have to scale the amount of green and red (and maybe some blue) you want, convert that to hex, and then concatenate them into this format. If you search for terms like "smooth color gradient" you will get some helpful examples to point you in the right direction.